# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firstappdjango'

Tags: django

I already install `django.all` is ok but 1 problem show me, again and again, that's

> ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'firstappdjango'

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you register your app in **`Settings`** file?

Comment: Edit your question and repost it with code along with error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `firstappdjango` is added to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'firstappdjango',
    ....
]
```

If your app is located within another directory within the root directory you will have to specify the full path:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'directory.firstappdjango',
    ....
]
```

Comment: when I added 'myapadjango' then show again problem no module name 'firstappdjangofirstappdjango' what I do now

Comment: Please update the question with traceback, directory structure and code.