# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxxdjango'

Tags: python, django, debugging, web

I've been looking thoroughly before asking this question but couldn't find the answer on Stack Overflow. [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firstappdjango'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52442715/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-firstappdjango) has a similar error but does not solve my problem.

I've launched default app without problems and got Django screen etc. I am following a tutorial now and I started simple app with some HTML response. I get error called `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adamprojectdjango'` when I want to run server.

What I've checked/some info

- my app is called `adamproject`
- app installed in `settings.py`

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
      'adamproject'
      'django.contrib.admin',
      'django.contrib.auth',
      'django.contrib.contenttypes',
      'django.contrib.sessions',
      'django.contrib.messages',
      'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  ]
  ```
- directories look as below

  ```
     /home/none/eclipse-workspace/test5
      ├── adamproject
      │   └── migrations
      └── test5
      └── __pycache__
  ```
- app config file:

  ```
  from django.apps import AppConfig
  class MysiteConfig(AppConfig):
      name = 'adamproject'
  ```

Comment: is the lack of a comma behind the first installed apps entry a typo or significant?

Comment: As per my comment below. This was typo.

Answer (score 6):

Consider the following:

```
my_string = 'adamproject' 'django.contrib.admin'
print(my_string)
# prints:
# adamprojectdjango.contrib.admin
```

You have a missing comma after 'adamproject'. So it is being concatenated to what you intended to be the subsequent list entry. This results in an attempt to load an app from the module `adamprojectdjango` which does not exist.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'adamproject'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

print(INSTALLED_APPS)
# prints:
# ['adamprojectdjango.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
```

Instead, your list of `INSTALLED_APPS` should be declared like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'adamproject',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I need to get in habit of checking things more thoroughly. Good lesson. Thanks!